# Autowired Bean in two classes not being updated after accessing it from the second class

Tags: java, spring, junit4, autowired

I have the following scenario:

A bean Autowired in two classes, I populate the bean in one class, then I check the bean in the second class, it is not populated. Whereas, when I add a getter in the class where I populated the bean and call the getter, it returns the bean populated. Why can't I access that bean directly in the other class, shouldn't it be populated since it's acting as a singleton in spring context?

A JUnit4 test class loading the spring context from an xml file:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/spring/test-main-context.xml" })
public class MyTests {

    @Autowired
    MyObject myObject;

    @Autowired
    MyUtils myUtils;

    @Test
    public void testingContext() {
        myUtils.setMyObjectFromDB();
        System.out.println(myUtils.getMyObject().getId());
        System.out.println(myObject.getId());
    }
}
```

MyUtils:

```
public class MyUtils {

    @Autowired MyObject myObject;

    public void setMyObjectFromDB() {
        MyObject myDBObject = new MyObject();
        //
        // getting myObjectFromDB;
        //
        myObject = myDBObject;
    }

    public MyObject getMyObject() {
        return myObject;
    }
}
```

In the test class, `myUtils.getMyObject().getId()` returns a correct id but the second line `myObject.getId()` it returns null.

Why is MyObject which is set in MyUtils class and is @Autowired in both classes is not being updated when I access it directly in the test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're reassigning `myObject = myDBObject;` in `setMyObjectFromDB` method, you're creating a new object and saving it's referene in `myObject` variable which is different from the one created with `Autowired`.

When you use `Autowired`, then it will assign the created bean's reference in the variable. But if you reassign that variable, it will point to the new object.

EDIT:

If you really need to update all the variables of `myObject` with initialized with `Autowired`, it is better to create a container class that stores `myObject` variable.

```
public class MyObjectContainer {
     @Autowired
     MyObject myObject;

     // Getters & Setters
}
```

In all the classes, where you're autowiring `myObject`, use an object of `MyObjectContainer` class instead. And when you want to update `myObject` value, just update it in `myObjectContainer` object with it's setter. So your `MyUtils` would be like:

```
public class MyUtils {

    @Autowired MyObjectContainer myObjectContainer;

    public void setMyObjectFromDB() {
        MyObject myDBObject = new MyObject();
        //
        // getting myObjectFromDB;
        //
        myObjectContainer.setMyObject(myDBObject);
    }

    public MyObjectContainer getMyObjectContainer() {
        return myObjectContainer;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can directly update by reference `this.myObject = myObject;`. And every time you'll access it through it's container object which will have the updated object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, the `MyObject` is not injected in either of the two classes. You got the impression that it was injected in the `MyUtils` class because you actually created it manually in the setter method.

The brings the question to why `MyObject` is not injected, and there could be many reasons for that one of which is that you do not have `@Component` defined in the `MyObject` class or it is not in your component scan path by adding `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "put-your-base-package-name")` in your Spring application class.

Comment: In that case, the failure would occur at the line where the autowiring is occuring.