# Spring - Listen for dependent bean changes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring application, i have BeanA that is used by BeanX, BeanY and BeanZ. When BeanA changes during its lifecycle, i want BeanX, BeanY and BeanZ get notified. Is there any out of the box way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at @EventListener, example https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-spring-framework-eventlistener.html

Comment: Reads like a bad code smell to me!

Comment: What kind of changes do you mean? If you want to track invocations of setter methods you can use Spring AOP.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53830819/4608329

Comment: @pkgajulapalli, no, it is not

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides Event handling in the `ApplicationContext` through the `ApplicationEvent` class and `ApplicationListener` interface.

Following event types are supported, one can use these for event handling.

```
ContextRefreshedEvent
ContextStartedEvent
ContextStoppedEvent
ContextClosedEvent
RequestHandledEvent
```

To listen to a context event, a bean should implement the `ApplicationListener` interface which has just one method `onApplicationEvent()`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement **Observer Pattern** for this.

In Spring, the Observer Pattern is used in the `ApplicationContext`’s event mechanism. When you deploy a bean that implements the `ApplicationListener` interface, it will receive an `ApplicationEvent` every time the event is published by an event publisher.

If you are creating your own custom event, your event publisher must implement  [ApplicationEventPublisherAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisherAware.html) interface. Publisher can publish an `ApplicationEvent` by calling the `publishEvent()` method of `ApplicationEventPublisher` instance.